# Не пушит новые commit на GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-push

Всем добрый день!

Совсем новенький с GitHub. Создал 2 тестовых коммита проекта. Запушил на первом и втором в ветку master и все сработало. После этого создал ещё 2 тестовых коммита. Снова попытался запушить командой git push origin master.

Выдало, что все хорошо: `Everything up-to-date`

Но на GitHub новые коммиты не отобразились. Там находятся только 2 первых.

Работаю только с веткой master - новых не создавал. Head сейчас находится на последнем - 4-ом коммите.

---

Вот информация с git log:

```
commit 7a1cc12c2bbbff3f70a394256871e27d57109c11 (HEAD)
Author: Nikolay Mareev <mareevn9@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Feb 19 01:12:20 2024 +0300

    Четвертая версия

commit a48b049e1a8877a92c5f88099734a0518776294c
Author: Nikolay Mareev <mareevn9@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Feb 19 01:05:05 2024 +0300

    Третья версия

commit 60d1d548ba90d7961e3bc3b583b96c6f12ce835a (origin/master, master)
Author: Nikolay Mareev <mareevn9@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Feb 19 00:49:34 2024 +0300

    Вторая тестовая версия

commit f57338f991f654884f1a731d817249eb490cc44a
Author: Nikolay Mareev <mareevn9@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Feb 19 00:48:27 2024 +0300

    Тестовая версия
```

---

Информация с git status:

```
HEAD detached at 7a1cc12
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

---

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть моя ошибка? Как запушить на гитхаб в ветку `master`?

Comment: вы с ветки соскользнули.  держитесь крепче

Answer (score 0):

`HEAD detached` говорит о том, что "голова" отделена. Вы, похоже, делали чекаут непосредственно на конкретный коммит какой-то, а не на ветку, и теперь надо голову, как раз, вернуть обратно на ветку.

---

Самое простое в вашем случае, может помочь слияние с быстрой перемоткой:

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff 7a1cc12c2bbbff3f70a394256871e27d57109c11
```

Это может сработать потому, что на мастере больше не было никаких коммитов после "отделения"

---

Либо переход обратно на ветку мастера и внесение в неё других коммитов:

1. Нужно ещё раз убедиться, что всё закоммичено в текущем...коммите
2. Далее перейти на свою рабочую ветку

   ```
   git checkout master
   ```
3. Если нужно, влить в неё коммиты 3 и 4, чтобы они там были:

   ```
   git cherry-pick <hash1> <hash2>
   ```
4. Сделать `push`

---

**NOTE:** Во время черри пикинга могут быть конфликты, которые надо будет решать. В терминале будут подсказки, так или иначе

Чтиво по черри пикингу:

- https://www.dev-notes.ru/articles/git/demystifying-git-cherry-pick/
- [https://www.atlassian.com/ru/git/tutorials/cherry-pick#:~:text=git%20cherry-pick%20—%20это%20полезная,это%20удобный%20способ%20отменить%20изменения](https://www.atlassian.com/ru/git/tutorials/cherry-pick#:%7E:text=git%20cherry-pick%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F,%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).
- [https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Распределённый-Git-Сопровождение-проекта#r_rebase_cherry_pick](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-Git-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0#r_rebase_cherry_pick)
- и т.д.

---

#### UPD: Как советуют в комментарии, можно сделать так:

```
git checkout HEAD -B master
```

Comment: Что-то как-то сложно, правильная команда тут - `git checkout HEAD -B master`, и никаких слияний или черрипиков...

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Проблема решена, благодаря Вашим советам)

Answer (score -2):

Если я ничего не путаю, HEAD означает, что изменения сделаны на локальном репозитории, origin/master - что внесены в ветку master на удаленном.
Возможно, Вы пропустили команду add, поэтому внесённые Выми изменения не закомитились и не запушились.

Comment: По приведённому git log они очевидно закоммитились